# Locally free sheaf on a connected ringed space is free

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne says if a locally free sheaf on a connected ringed space has a constant rank. Can I deduce further that the sheaf is actually free (globally) on the ringed space? If not is there any counter example?

Comment: The tangent bundle on projective space, or any non-elliptic curve.

Comment: @Arthur,@Gunnar What is the relation between bundles and sheaves of modules?

Answer (score 1):

Given the ring $\Bbb Z_6$ of integers modulo $6$, and the $\Bbb Z_6$-module $\Bbb Z_2$ (with module structure given by the standard quotient map $\Bbb Z_6\to\Bbb Z_2$ and regular multiplication), let $X = \operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z_6$ be our ringed space and the induced $\mathscr O_X$-module $\Gamma = \widetilde{\Bbb Z_2}$ be our sheaf. I claim that it is locally free, but not free.

$X$ has two points, $(2)$ and $(3)$, and its distinguished open sets are:
$$
X = D_1 = D_5\\
\{(3)\} = D_2 = D_4\\
\{(2)\} = D_3\\
\varnothing = D_0
$$
We have
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
U&\mathscr O_X(U)&\Gamma(U)\\
\hline
D_1&\Bbb Z_6&\Bbb Z_2\\
D_2&\Bbb Z_3&0\\
D_3&\Bbb Z_2&\Bbb Z_2\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$D_2$ and $D_3$ covers all of $X$, and on both of those, $\Gamma$ is free. However, $\Gamma$ is not a free sheaf globally.

Comment: This looks reasonable. A small question: $\tilde{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ (also in Hartshorne, it is defined for any $A$-module $M$). Is it not the sheafification of constant presheaf $M$, is it?

Comment: @Upc I don't have my Hartshorne here at the moment, and it's been a few years, so I don't recall the exact name. But the sheaf $\widetilde{M}$ is constructed basically the same way the structure sheaf $\mathscr O_X$ itself is: on a distinguished open set $D_r\subseteq X$, we have that $\widetilde M(D_r)$ is the localisation $M_r$ given by allowing powers of $\frac 1r$. These are the basic building blocks of (quasi)coherent sheaves.

Comment: I don't remember whether it's the sheafification. Sorry.

Comment: A locally free sheaf corresponds to a projective module from ring theory. In other words, a module which is a _direct summand_ of a free module. This example works because $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$ is a free $\Bbb Z_6$-module, making $\Bbb Z_2$ projective.

Comment: Thanks. I think they are different. The sections of the constant sheaf $\underline{A}$ over an open set $U$ may be interpreted as the continuous functions $U\to A$, where $A$ is given the discrete topology. I don't see there is a localization process.

Comment: And the answers above in the comment mentioned bundles. What is the relation between bundles and sheaves of modules.

Comment: @Upc A (vector) bundle is a sheaf of vector spaces over some base space, and vector spaces are modules over a field. These base spaces are usually manifolds, though, rather than schemes.

Comment: Sorry, why does $X$ have 3 points in it? $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not an integral domain so maybe $(0)$ should be excluded?

Comment: @PlatoEinsYu You know, I think you're right.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/6 \cong \Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/3$, so $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z/6$ is the disjoint union of $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z/2$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z/3$, i.e. it is disconnected. See my answer for a counterexample on a connected scheme.

Answer (score 0):

No, you may not deduce that a locally free sheaf is free. Here is a simple counterexample.

Consider the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-1)$ on $\Bbb P^n$ (which is connected). Then $\Gamma(\Bbb P^n,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-1))=0$, so any morphism from a free sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}^{\oplus I}\to\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-1)$ is zero. In particular, $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}^{\oplus I}\not\cong\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-1)$, so it isn't a free sheaf, but $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(-1)$ is still locally free.